# Unable to open qtspim in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, qt

I recently downloaded latest version of qtspim from https://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/ in ubuntu 20.04 .Then after clicking on deb file it automatically downloaded software from ubuntu software. After clicking icon of qtspim it is not opening. Can anyone help me

Comment: please help me . I have to do some assignment.

Comment: Opens OK here with the "icon" ( `/usr/share/applications/qtspim.desktop` ). ........ You can also do the command  `$ qtspim` to start the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation is straightforward - download deb-file and install it with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://deac-riga.dl.sourceforge.net/project/spimsimulator/qtspim_9.1.22_linux64.deb
sudo apt install ./qtspim_9.1.22_linux64.deb
```

Comment: Thank a lot !!! it worked